# codenameone virtual keyboard not getting displayed in android device

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to display a virtual keyboard when TextField is focused. When I tested it on an Android phone, its default keyboard is being shown and not the customized one.

```
    Form testForm = new Form(new BorderLayout());
    TextField txt = new TextField(); 

    String[][] arrOfNumbers = new String[][]{{"1","2","3",}, {"4","5","6",}, {"7","8","9",}, {"0", "00", "$OK$"}};

    VirtualKeyboard virtualKB = new VirtualKeyboard(); 
    virtualKB.addInputMode("NUM_KB", arrOfNumbers);
    virtualKB.setInputModeOrder(new String[]{"NUM_KB"});
    VirtualKeyboard.bindVirtualKeyboard(txt, virtualKB);

    testForm.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, txt);        
    testForm.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The virtual keyboard class is a part of legacy functionality and shouldn't be used. Codename One uses native input, your code will work with the native numeric input by using:

```
Form testForm = new Form(new BorderLayout());
TextField txt = new TextField(); 
txt.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC);

testForm.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, txt);        
testForm.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Shai for your response. In this case, I want to display a numeric keyboard with a couple of special keys and different look (e.g. display all keys in a single horizontal line). How do I do that?

Comment: Native keyboards don't allow that level of customization unless you implement a VKB from scratch which isn't portable. If you want full control you can just use a dialog with buttons.